# PHPExcel : CodeIgniter error on output

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have this controller which renders my data from database to the PHPExcel library.

> https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/

this is my controller :

```
public function downloadTournamentData() {
    $this->load->model("Tournament");

    $var_data = array();

    $var_data['tournament'] = $this->Tournament->getTournamentData();

    $this->load->library('excel');

    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('test');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'member_username');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'member_name');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'member_phone');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'member_email');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'member_idcard');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'Date_created');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', 'team_name');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', 'warnet_name');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1', 'warnet_cp');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1', 'warnet_phone');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1', 'region_name');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1', 'City');


    $cell_inc = 2;
    foreach($var_data['tournament'] as $k => $v) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$cell_inc, $v['member_username']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$cell_inc, $v['member_name']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$cell_inc, $v['member_phone']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$cell_inc, $v['member_email']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$cell_inc, $v['member_idcard']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$cell_inc, $v['Date_created']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$cell_inc, $v['team_name']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$cell_inc, $v['warnet_name']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$cell_inc, $v['warnet_cp']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$cell_inc, $v['warnet_phone']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$cell_inc, $v['region_name']);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$cell_inc, $v['City']);

        $cell_inc++;
    }

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");

    $this_date = date("Y-m-d");

    $filename='pb_turnamen_data-'.$this_date.'.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

It does download the excel file. Only problem is that the data is mixed up and it's all wrong.

[image: Screenshot of downloaded excel file]

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my controller?

**Please provide solution...**

Comment: Is it prompting you to choose character set while opening it in excel? Try setting character set to UTF-8 while opening it to excel.

Comment: If you're sending a spreadsheet directly to the browser, then there must be absolutely no additional output generated anywhere within your code or by the framework

Comment: @DishaV. : no, it doesn't prompt me to set the charset. The error is "The file format and extension of 'xxx.xls' don't match..."

Comment: @MarkBaker : I don't see any additional output being generated after / before the header and createWriter. But I'm not reading a spreadsheet, I'm generating one from database data.

Could the issue lies with the way I load the PHPExcel library?
Does CodeIgniter have limitation on loading this library?

Answer (score 2):

Add 
ob_end_clean(); 
after 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');

final code is

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```